# Access Returned Object Properties from Router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I start my server using nodemon which starts the server on localhost 8080

I go to localhost:8080/api which returns:

`[{"date":"1587946153337","_id":"5ea622b6334c4de9fa307b20","post":"This is the first post!","__v":0},{"date":"1603312852793","_id":"5f909d49d75c9b1ec2e39ee7","post":"this is a test","__v":0},{"date":"1603313042345","_id":"5f909dea89eeee2d40e933c6","post":"this is a second test post","__v":0},{"date":"1603483744050","_id":"5f9338b12e575d3935b0b16b","post":"hiiii","__v":0},{"date":"1603483572093","_id":"5f9338b264236f36c48c3a60","post":"e","__v":0},{"date":"1604349323678","_id":"5fa06dcd59aeeba1e1845c0f","post":"was","__v":0}]`

How can I gain access to the properties that are returned? For example, I want to display the post property as HTML.

The object that seems to hold the properties is `data` from `api.js`

```
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const https = require("https");

const Post = require('../models/post');  // This is the model to use

// Routes
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Post.find( {  })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Data: ', data);
            const log = res.json(data);
            //console.log(log);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error: ', daerrorta);  
        });
});
```

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const routes = require('./routes/api');

const postString = "test";
const commentString = "test";
const profString = "test";
const univString = "test";

// MONGODB ACCOUNT INFO:
// Usermame: MyCampusAdmin
// Password: AdminForMyCampus

// MongoDB URI
const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb+srv://MyCampusAdmin:AdminForMyCampus@mycampus-whyic.mongodb.net/MyCampus?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/MyCampus', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose is connected');
});

// Data parsing
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// HTTP request logger
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use('/api', routes);

//function makePost(p) {
    // p = postString;

    // postData
    // const postData = {
    //     post: p,
    //     univID: 1,
    //     numLikes: 0
    // };

    // Post Save
    // const newPost = new Post(postData);  // Instance of the new model

    // Post Save
    //  newPost.save((error) => {
    //      if (error) {
    //          console.log('Something went wrong with post save');
    //      }
    //      else {
    //          console.log('Post data has ben saved');
    //      }
    //  });
//}

function makeComment(c) {
    c = commentString;

    // commentData
    const commentData = {
        comment: c,
        postID: 1,
        numLikes: 0
    };

    // Comment Save
    const newComment = new Comment(commentData);

    // Comment Save
    newComment.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong with comment save');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Comment data has ben saved');
        }
    });
}

function addProf(pr) {
    pr = profString;

    // profData
    const profData = {
        name: pr, 
        univID: 1,
        department: "SE",
        classes: "Applied Research"
    };

    // Prof Save
    const newProf = new Prof(profData);

    // Prof Save
    newProf.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong with prof save');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Prof data has ben saved');
        }
    });
}

function addUniv(u) {
    u = univString;

    // univData
    const univData = {
        university: u
    };

    // University Save
    const newUniv = new University(univData);

    // Universoty Save
    newUniv.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong with university save');
        }
        else {
            console.log('University data has ben saved');
        }
    });
}



 // COMMENT SET UP
 // Comment Schema Declaration
 const SchemaComment = mongoose.Schema;
 // Comment Schema
 const CommentSchema = new SchemaComment ({
     comment: String,
     postID: Number,
     date: {
         type: String,
         default: Date.now()
     },
     numLikes: Number,
 });
 // Comment Model
 const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);

 //PROF SET UP
 // Prof Schema Declaration
 const SchemaProf = mongoose.Schema;
 // Professor Schema
 const ProfSchema = new SchemaProf ({
     name: String,
     univID: Number,
     department: String,
     classes: String
 });
 // Professor Model
 const Prof = mongoose.model('Professor', ProfSchema);
 // UNIV SET UP
 // University Schema Declaration
 const SchemaUniv = mongoose.Schema;

 // University Schema
 const UnivSchema = new SchemaUniv ({
     university: String,
 });
 // University Model
 const University = mongoose.model('University', UnivSchema);


//TESTING FUNCTIONS
// makePost(postString);
// makeComment(commentString);
// addProf(profString);
// addUniv(univString); 




app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));

//app.listen(3000, function(){
//    console.log("Server 3000");
//});

/*
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/AccountSetUp.jsx");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/AccountSetUp.jsx");
});
*/
```

Here is my api.js

```
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const https = require("https");

const Post = require('../models/post');  // This is the model to use

// Routes
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Post.find( {  })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Data: ', data);
            const log = res.json(data);
            //console.log(log);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error: ', daerrorta);  
        });
});

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    
    https.get(Post, function(response){
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    })

    res.send("hello")
})

router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Body: ', req.body);
    const data = req.body;

    const newPost = new Post(data);
    newPost.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json({ msg: 'Sorry, internal server errors'});
        }
        else {
            // Post
            res.json({
                msg: 'Your data has been saved!!'
            });
        }
    });
});

router.get('/name', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        username: 'name',
        age: 20
    };
    res.json(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is all the code I have for the component that is to fetch and render the data. I'm not sure how to access the data returned from `router.get` in this component.

DisplayPost.tsx

```
import { router } from "../routes/api";

export const DisplayPost = () => {
    return(
        <>
        <div>Welcome</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? 
Seems like you are returning the array from the call, so you can iterate through that array and access the ```post``` property

Comment: I've tried using any suggestions I can find. Such as using ``componentDidMount`` and ``JSON.Parse()``. I haven't tried iterating through the array. Are you suggesting I can use a loop to iterate through the ```data``` array? I didn't try that yet but am not sure how to structure that into code or where to put it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the code you have for the component that is fetching and rendering the data. 
Your data is just an array (list)  and you can use ```map``` to iterate through it and render the specific part of it: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html You can read more in here

Comment: I uploaded my component that will do the rendering. Would I map it in my ```DisplayPost.tsx``` component? So essentially I am trying to map the array like so: ```data.map(Post)``` ? I've tried implementing it following your link, but have trouble declaring or importing that array in my new component ```DisplayPost.tsx```

Comment: So where do you fetch the data? This is just the empty component, so do you do a fetch in a parent component?

Comment: The fetching is done in the ```api.js``` file. It is the first code block that I shared. That ```get``` is what's returning my array. I just don't know where to go from there to actually utilize that array that is returned.